# Passing a variable from one class to sendkeys function of another class

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am reading data from excel in one class and trying to pass the value in the sendkeys function of another class but it is not working.It is not typing the text read from excel into the textbox. I have verified that the data is read correctly from the excel.

I am using the below codes.

### DataLibrary.java

```
public class DataLibrary {
    public static WebDriver driver;
    protected static String username;
    protected String password;

    @Test
    public void readData() throws IOException, Exception, Throwable {

        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("./TestData/Data.xlsx");
        Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(fis);
        Sheet sh = wb.getSheet("Data");

        username = sh.getRow(1).getCell(1).getStringCellValue();
        password = sh.getRow(2).getCell(1).getStringCellValue();

    }

}
```

### Login.java

```
public class Login extends DataLibrary {

    public static WebDriver driver;

    @BeforeMethod

    public void LoginProcess() throws InterruptedException {

        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("URL");
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        // Username in Login Page
        driver.findElement(By.id("_58_loginText")).sendKeys(username);

        // Password in Login Page
        driver.findElement(By.id("_58_password")).sendKeys(password);

        // Click on Sign In Button
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button")).click();
        Thread.sleep(2000);

        // Click on Apply Button in Home Page
        driver.findElement(By.id("applyButton")).click();
    }
}
```

When I am passing username and password in the sendkeys in the above code, it is not working. Shows no error but it is not entering the text in UI.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is the `readData()` method ever called?

Comment: which testing framework are you using `JUnit`/`TestNG`?

Comment: @nullpointer Using TestNG

Comment: @jlordo Nopes. And I don't think it's required as well for my code. I just need to pass the variable in sendkeys. If I execute a normal print statement to print the username/password fetched text then I can see that. The problem seems to be something related to passing it in sendKeys().

Comment: where did you place your `print`statement?

Comment: @jlordo I had used the print statement in both the classes to check whether I am getting the value or not. I was able to get the value and print it without any issue.

Comment: If you manually write a string into sendkeys, it works?

Comment: @RafaelAlmeida Yes, it works absolutely fine.

Answer (score 1):

it's a very silly mistake, you have put @BeforeMethod where you should have put @Test and visa versa, and so what is happening is **LoginProcess** method runs before **readData** method and so you get null values.

change it like mentioned below and everything will work. I have removed to code related to excel and webdriver but it's easy to understand.

```
public class DataLibrary {
    protected static String username;
    protected String password;

    @BeforeMethod
    public void readData() {
        username = "gaurang";
        password = "shah";
    }
}
```

and then your test case

```
public class Login extends DataLibrary {

    @Test
    public void LoginProcess() throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println(username);
        System.out.println(password);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I figured out the issue. I was actually just executing the Login class without even calling the readData() method in the Login class. Got it now. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @preetam88 putting the @BeforeMethod annotation on the `readData` method will insure it gets run before your test. IMO this is still the correct answer. If you want to read the data before each test that `DataLibrary` is attached to(For example by having `Login` extend `DataLibrary`), this is the correct approach.

Comment: @preetam88 none of the approach is good. I just though there are some minror issue in your code and so I showed you how to fix it. Your data layer should be abstract from code layer and that should be the best approach. Do some google search on how to do it, if you are just beginning with you framework.